Is there an algebraic way to find the interval of a multivariable function if univariable functions are given?
Suppose given $-3\leq x \leq 2$ and $1\leq y \leq 5$, How am I supposed to find the interval for $x^2+y^2$?
At first, I thought this problem could've been solved when I squared those 2 statements i.e.
$$4\leq x^2 \leq 9$$
and
$$1\leq y^2 \leq 25$$
Then, (I don't know were this incorrect or even allowed)
$$\{4\leq x^2 \leq 9 \}\cup \{1\leq y^2 \leq 25\} = \{5\leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 34 \}$$
Later on, I realized that I got the first interval written incorrectly, since I believe, it should be
$$\{0\leq x^2 \leq 9 \}$$
I was just lucky that I still got the right answer though my first assumption of the interval is incorrect. My question is, is there a formal algebraic way to solve this kind of question? I was thinking about Lagrange Multiplier to find the max and the min when I have to assume that the constraints are
$$x+y = -2$$
and
$$x+y=7$$
(I got those two by adding the first two intervals)
However I didn't get the interval $$[1,\, 34]$$
as the answer. Was I thinking incorrectly?

Why do you claim that $4\leqslant x^2\leqslant9$? After all, $x$ can well be $0$.

@JoséCarlosSantos at first I just squared all three sides.

In fact, you can get the answer by calculate $x$ and $y$ respectively.
Since $0 \le x^2 \le 9$ and $1 \le y^2 \le 25$, take $x^2=0,y^2=1$, we get the minimum $x^2+y^2=1$. Take $x^2=9,y^2=25$, we get the maximun  $x^2+y^2=34$.
Notice the binary map $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, where $f$ is continuous, all the value in $[1,34]$ can be taken.
